# Exception handling with scala futures

Tags: scala, future

I have a problem with Scala Futures. I have a function that takes two parameters: x: Future[Int] and y: Future[Int].

The function should return a future that completes with:

- value of x if x completes successfully,
- value of y if x fails and y completes successfully,
- the exception that failed y if x fails and y fails.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

The code currently:

```
def myFunction(x: Future[Int], y: Future[Int]): Future[Int] = {
  x.onSuccess {
    case result => return Future(result)
  }
  x.onFailure {
    case e => 
      y.onSuccess {
        case res => return Future(res)
      }
      y.onFailure {
        case f => throw f
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply:

```
x.recoverWith { case _ => y }
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!